# Information about Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, statistics, user-information

I am interested in some information about Stack Exchange, like

1. How can I find the question with the maximum number of answers?
2. How can I list all moderators of Stack Overflow?
3. How to list users that have maximum reputation for all Stack Exchange sites? I know for Stack Overflow it's Jon Skeet. I can get this information by going on each site and clicking on users and see the maximum reputation user of all time, but is there any query to list all in one?
4. The person who got the highest upvote for an answer and the same for a question?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The question with the maximum number of answers:

Via data.stackexchange.com:

```
select ParentId
from Posts
group by ParentId
order by count(ParentId) DESC
```

Result:
636 answers for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes
528 answers for [What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered)

### Stack Overflow moderators:

https://stackoverflow.com/about (scroll down)

### All time highest rep users across all sites:

Closest thing right now is "feature users" on this page: https://stackexchange.com/sites (scroll down, right side)

### Highest voted question and answer?

via data.stackexchange.com:

```
select Id
from Posts
where PostTypeId = 1
order by Score DESC
```

Change the PostTypeId to 2 to get highest scoring answers.

Question: 2330 votes for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books
Answer: 4351 votes for [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)